# Can't cat a public read file

Tags: bash, shell, linux-mint

Having the following file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 887 Aug 25 13:18 /etc/ssl/private/livereload.key
```

Can't manage to read it from a regular user instance.

```
$ cat /etc/ssl/private/livereload.key
cat: /etc/ssl/private/livereload.key: Permission denied
```

I was wandering why since the file seems to be public for reading.
Did I miss-set something when I generated the file ?

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory?  If you don't have `x` permissions you can't access files within the directory, even if you have permission to the file itself.

Comment: Check for `+x` on `ssl & private`

Comment: For more on directory permissions see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work/21252

Comment: The parent directory's permissions are `drwx--x--- 2 root ssl-cert`. You are rigth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

default permissions are as below on /etc/ssl. So others can not read this directory. root user or group member of ssl-cert can only read this file, if default permissions not been changed.

```
ls -alrt /etc/ssl/
drwx--x---   2 root ssl-cert  4096 Dec 19  2014 private


user@host:/etc/ssl$ cd /etc/ssl/private/
bash: cd: /etc/ssl/private/: Permission denied
```

you can use this;

```
sudo cat /etc/ssl/private/livereload.key
```